# force https on a single page, and then redirect other requests to http

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hello so basically i have a single page that i want to have https, i want its children and siblings to have http only.

i have the code working some what, however if i click a link from my ssl page to a non ssl page the https still stays., i am trying to get it to redirect back to http

here is what i have so far

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^prepaid/?$ https://www.domain.com/prepaid/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^prepaid/h2o/?$  index.php?p=prepaid&s=h2o [L]
RewriteRule ^prepaid/?$      index.php?p=prepaid       [L]
```

main goal is to force www at all times as well as trailing slash
also want to force https only on https://www.domain.com/prepaid/ and then any childeren or sibliligs im trying to force http. even if you are on the https page and you click away (this is what im stuck on, it currently stays in https)

Comment: You should really just update the links to be full paths, i.e. specfiy `http://example.com/foo.html`, rather than just foo.html, this way there is nothing to do except force ssh on that one page, which is a single RewriteCond/RewriteRule combination.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<Location /sample.php>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</Location>
```

rename sample.php to your filename

Comment: that won't work, the file is a common template get file (index.php) and the pages differ by the get vars (index.php?p=prepaid)

Comment: replace sample.php to index.php?p=prepaid I hope it should work